# mongoose.findOneAndUpdate returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am using mongoose.findOneAndUpdate() method for inserting and updating a document in the collection. However if there is nothing to update in the table and a new document is created, the findOneAndUpdate() callback returns null.

*How would I know if the insert part of the findOneAndUpdate() was successfull?*

```
TimeTable.getTimeTableModelObject().findOneAndUpdate({ageGroup:'2'}, timeTable, {upsert:true}, function(err, foundData){});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate

> Available options
>
> new: bool - if true, return the modified document rather than the original. defaults to false
>
> [...]

Also, you can just check for `err` in your callback function.

Comment: If I set `new` to be true, will it return NON NULL value in the callback for the document that were added THE FIRST TIME? There can be a scenario where mongoose couldn't insert the document in the collection without causing an error. In that case `err` will not be set

Comment: Yes, when using `upsert:true` it will return the new document after insertion. "There can be a scenario where mongoose couldn't insert the document in the collection without causing an error." I don't think so. What scenario would that be?

Comment: it's not returning the new document after insertion. I am already using upsert=true

Comment: @user2498079 did you ever figure this out? this is clearly not a duplicate of the linked question

Comment: @CQM I agree with you, you can vote for `Reopen` below the question ^^